# Redirect to Home page if user already logged in, in same browser asp .net c#

Tags: asp.net

I want to make application that if user in logged in the web site in one tab of browser and if he open application in second tab than he should not redirect to login page but he should redirect to Home page. just like Facebook or yahoomail in asp.net C#

please help

Comment: As far as I know, [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) collection would do this

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should use a persistent auth cookie. This will allow authentication to be maintained across tabs. It's a flag when you authenticate users, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx).

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("name", true); // persistant auth cookie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom session attribute in Session_Start method in Global.asax, and when home page loads check that assigned session still available or not, if it exists still then redirect to logged page.

if (Session["UserId"] != null){Response.Redirect("/home/Index");}

I hope this will help you.