# Logged in user doesn't go to the home page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

As a currently logged in user, when I go to the website, I'm redirected to a page that's doesn't currently exist (it sends me to the view article page, but doesn't display anything as it doesn't have any query parameters). I've searched around and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/27054856/397186 but its from a couple years ago, so I don't know if a better approach exists using Identity 2.0.

The question is: How can I redirect currently logged in users to the home page when they go to the website?

**UPDATE 2016-10-08**

Here are some screen shots showing the error: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5GjmejMcNuCM3RHNXBlbGNKYWs?usp=sharing

I *really* don't want to go with the Session_Start method. Let's say I've bookmarked a page on the site, and when they click on that bookmark it takes them to the home page. Not very friendly.

This web app uses MVC 5.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `when they go to the website`? Do you mean you want to redirect user to home page right after login?

Comment: After login is working well. It's people that are already logged in and come back to the site.

Comment: `people that are already logged in and come back to the site` Where did they login? Did they authenticate outside of your site like single-sign-on, and then redirect back to your site after login successful?

Comment: They logged in using the login form provided with ASP.Net Identity.

Comment: Well, what address do they go to when they come back to your site? Is it `example.com` or `example.com/path/does/not/exist`?

Comment: It should be example.com, but it currently goes to a page that doesn't exist. (it's the view article page, but since there aren't and parameters in the URL, it goes to a article doesn't exist page)

Comment: @ajtatum what do you mean "goes"? do users get 301 redirect status to `example.com/page/does/not/exist/` when they type `example.com`?

Comment: Updated the post so it wouldn't get lost in the comments, but you can see what I'm talking about here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5GjmejMcNuCM3RHNXBlbGNKYWs?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems like using a system-level approach is a way to go. Why would you comment it out if it works? Also, put break points so you can see where and what is being executed if the code is commented out in `Session_Start ()`

Comment: It just seems like I should have to do that... I believe there's a better method or something that's widely accept. I doubt all the other MVC sites out there don't need to do the session start method.  Also, let's say some bookmarks the "Articles" page and when they go to that bookmark it just takes them to the home page. Not very user friendly...

Comment: Is this asp.net-mvc or not.  Your example code is highly questionable with the asp.net-mvc framework (basically not how the framework would want you to do what you want).

Comment: This is an MVC web app

Comment: when you try to go back to home page, do you see any return url parameter added at the end of the link?

Comment: Nope there is nothing in the querystring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is an MVC application.

Go to `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` or try to find another place where RegisterRoutes() is implemented.

Show us what this function looks like.

It should look something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Important is the part after "defaults". This should contain "Home", "Index" and not some other information

Also check that `RegisterRoutes()` is actually executed. It should be called from `Application_Start()` in your `Global.asax.cs` file.

Comment: It looks like:
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "oandp_redesign_web.Controllers" }
                );

Comment: Try to disable the call to `MapMvcAttributeRoutes`. If this helps, check the Controller classes in the project for attributes that make a controller use the default route, If not, check whether the `RegisterRoutes()`is actually called during runtime.

Comment: So I commented out routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); and the session_start stuff in Global.asax.cs... and it works as expected. Went to the page I bookmarked and it took me straight there. I do use AttributRoutes though. If I get rid of it, I'd have to map a bunch of routes in the RouteConfig.cs. Again, I'd assume many people have MapMvcAttributeRoutes on and it works the same. Not sure what's going on. Thank you for your help on this issue. If you have any ideas why it's not working as expected, lmk.

Comment: As I said you have to look through your controllers. In some controller, you use an attribute that makes that controller to the default route. Probably the controller that is involved with displaying the article pages.

Comment: I had a route: [Route("Articles/ViewArticle/{date:datetime}/{id}")]

Changed it to: [Route("ViewArticle/{date:datetime}/{id}")]

I enabled map mvc attributes and going to the bookmark takes me to the right page. I have no idea why that was causing the errors.